# Запустить крон задачу

Tags: ubuntu, bash, cron

Я использовал `crontab -e` и добавил новую задачу

```
@daily /etc/webmin/mysql/backup.pl --all
0 0 * * * /etc/webmin/fsdump/backup.pl 90881498558004
* * * * * cd /var/www/partners.dev/ && .bin/drush cron --root=web
* * * * * cd /var/www/partners.test/ && .bin/drush cron --root=web
*/1 * * * * /scripts/test.sh
```

code test.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

LOG_DIR=/var/log/script_backup/;
LOG_NAME=crone.log;
NOW=$(date +'%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S');

function write_log(){
    mkdir -p ${LOG_DIR};
    sudo sh -c "echo '$1' >> $LOG_DIR$LOG_NAME"
}

write_log ${NOW};
```

Я выполнил `sudo service cron restart`, но файл crole.log пустой.

Comment: **1**. Если в системе есть MTA - смотрите почту того юзера, от имени которого запускается задача в кроне. Ошибки выполнения будут указаны в письме. **2**. Проверьте, есть ли у юзера (от имени которого запускается) права "беспарольно" использовать `sudo`. Строка  `sudo sh - c...` может не отрабатывать.

Comment: У вас есть тут еще специфика: вы делаете бекап. Часто бывают ситуации, когда какой-то файл не доступен под пользователем, делающим бекап (банально, какой-то файл сделали "не с теми правами"). Поэтому делайте бекап под рутом.

Answer (score 4):

Ошибка в строке

```
sudo sh -c "echo '$1' >> $LOG_DIR$LOG_NAME"
```

`sudo` под кроном не будет работать (если не настроите через `/etc/sudoers`).

Часто бывают ситуации, когда какой-то файл не доступен под пользователем, делающим бекап. Поэтому делайте бекап под рутом.

Варианты решения:

## Вариант 1. Редактирование файла `/etc/crontab`

Формат такой же, что и у крона, только добавился пользователь, от имени которого будет запущена команда:

```
# m  h dom mon dow user  command
  *  * *   *   *   root  /scripts/test.sh
```

В качестве user следует указать root, и удалить `sudo` из скрипта. Скрипт будет запущен под `root`. Права доступа для `root` не проверяются вообще. Например, можете сделать `chmod 000 /path` - рут туда сможет и войти, и записать.

## Вариант 2. Запустить cron для пользователя root

`sudo crontab -e`

Это - задания для рута, будут выполняться также с повышенными привилегиями.

## Вариант 3. Настроить права на каталог

Настройте права на каталог `/var/log/script_backup/`: поставьте подходящую группу текущего пользователя (в примере `yourgroup`) и права на запись для группы:

```
sudo chmod g+w /var/log/script_backup/
sudo chown :yourgroup /var/log/script_backup/
```

Comment: `dom mon` что это?

Comment: dom - day of month, mon - month, то же что и у "обычного" крона, добавился только пользователь, от которого происходит запуск

Comment: Я убрал sudo, как вы и сказали, и изменил строку */1 * * * * /scripts/test.sh на */1 * * * * bash /scripts/test.sh

Comment: Где заменили? `sudo crontab -e` или `crontab -e`? Можно без `bash`, если стоит атрбут выполнения (`chmod +x  /scripts/test.sh`)

Comment: открыл `crontab -e` и там поменял

Comment: `изменил строку */1 * * * * /scripts/test.sh на */1 * * * * bash /scripts/test.sh` это не поможет. Вы по сути ничего не поменяли. Если хотите под root - выберите вариант 1 или 2. Я обновил ответ

Comment: но теперь все работает)))

Comment: Значит дело было в sudo, и его просто не нужно было использовать. И с доступами к каталогу все в порядке

Comment: @SanychHoilo если вам помог ответ, то отметьте его как верный